# Forbid to copy a variable

Tags: c#

I have a class Foo which contains a pointer to unmanaged memory from C dll. It implements IDisposable to free unmanaged memory using C dll and some other functionality with that ptr using dll.

```
public unsafe class Foo : IDisposable {
    void* ptr;

    internal Foo() { 
        /* initialize ptr from C dll */
    };

    public int getInfo() {
        /* return info from ptr using dll */
    }

    public Dispose() {
        /* free ptr using C dll */
    }
}
```

Also I have a factory which returns an exemplar of Foo object:

```
public unsafe class FooFactory {
    public Foo createFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Finally I have a function which takes Foo as argument, processes it and returns:

```
public Foo process(Foo f) {
    /* do some stuff with f */
    return f;
}
```

All I want to do is to prevent user from creating Foo object, storing it in a variable and passing that variable to a `process` with saving result to another variable, because it may be unsafe in such example:

```
Foo f2 = null;
using (var f1 = FooFactory.createFoo()) {
    // inside one can work with f1 and f2
    f2 = process(f1);
}

// but outside f1's ptr is already destroyed in C dll and f2 can not use it
f2.getInfo();
```

I want them use only on of these approaches, as they are safe:

```
using var f1 = FooFactory.createFoo();
f1 = process(f1);

// or
using var f1 = process(FooFactory.createFoo());
```

In C++ I can do it using std::unique_ptr as it is not copyable. Is there any way to do it in C#?

Comment: A notion of ownership can't be implemented in C# since you can't prevent copying. What you can do is make the class track whether it has been disposed (set a field, using `Interlocked.CompareExchange` for free thread safety), and have all methods/property accesses that would be unsafe throw `ObjectDisposedException` if they're used after disposing. This does not prevent the unsafe thing from happening, but is still better than (say) relying on memory access exceptions (including null reference exceptions). Simple use-after-disposed scenarios (same method) can be detected by a static analyzer.

Comment: For correctly implementing the IDisposable, visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/259206) famous answer (especially if you decide to put finalizer into the game).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing comes to mind to exactly match that pattern.

Instead, I would expect the `Foo` type to raise an [`ObjectDisposedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.objectdisposedexception?view=net-5.0) if I tried to use `f2` after leaving the `using` block. Checking status and throwing that exception might be one of the first responsibilities of the `getInfo()` (and similar) methods. The `using` pattern is pretty-strongly engrained among C# developers, where no one writing this code would be surprised by this behavior.

This is also one of the rare cases where you may want to implement a [finalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors) for the C# type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't forbid that, but you can make the `Foo` class safer by adding some code:

```cs
public unsafe class Foo : IDisposable
{
    void* ptr;

    internal Foo()
    {
        /* initialize ptr from C dll */
    }

    public int getInfo()
    {
        if (ptr is null) { // <==== test whether ptr is still valid!
            return 0; // or throw an exception.
        }
        /* return info from ptr using dll */
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        /* free ptr using C dll */
        ptr = null; // <==== set ptr = null when disposed!
    }
}
```